# Using arbitrary mySQL Query with JugglingDB?

Tags: mysql, node.js, jugglingdb

I am currently using juggling db with NodeJS for ORM. I now need to do some reporting, which involves joining data from several tables using arbitrary SQL with SUM and GROUP BY too. How would I do this using the jugglingdb framework, and get a list of objects containing data from several columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access to the query function from the *mysql* package using the adapter **client**:

```
var Schema = require('jugglingdb').Schema;
var schema = new Schema('mysql', {
 // your config
});

schema.client.query('your very wild query', function(err, data) {
 // data will be an Array of Objects if no error
});
```

Actually this is a direct call to the `query` function of [node-mysql](https://npmjs.org/package/mysql) package

Comment: So what does the very wild query actually look like?  It doesn't look like "SELECT * FROM  TABLE_NAME WHERE id=1", does it?  I've been trying to create different queries, but it doesn't seem to be firing them off...

Comment: Nevermind... I'm using the postgres adapter, and instead of `schema.client.query`, I had to user `schema.adapter.query`.

Comment: @incutonez I have used `schema.adapter.query`. But it shows that `function(err,data){
            //funtion body
         } has no method 'pop'`

Comment: No method `pop`?  I'm not quite sure what you're using it for or how... does `schema.client.query` work for you?