# Use jugglingdb to select results where an id exists in another table

Tags: mysql, node.js, jugglingdb

I'm attempting to use jugglingdb (and the mysql adapter) to grab a list of Patients. Our schema is setup so that a Patient must be a User, but a User does not have to be a Patient. This means a Patient has a userId, and the User table holds the name of the patient.

```
Patient
    id
    userId
User
    id
    givenName
    familyName
    middleInitial
```

When the initial pages were created, we simply used `Patient.all` to grab the results, and `patient.user(...` to grab the user object/username. This is fine for a small amount of records, but not for thousands of records.

How do I grab a list of Users, only if their id is referenced in the Patient table? Example mysql query:

```
SELECT * FROM User WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM Patient) AND familyName LIKE '%doe%';
```

I've been browsing the [jugglingdb-mysql adapter](https://github.com/jugglingdb/mysql-adapter) for a bit now and haven't found an ideal solution, otherwise, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17293145/using-arbitrary-mysql-query-with-jugglingdb) is the only other solution I've found so far.

Another alternative/query I could use is creating an inner join between Patient and User and then filter the results:

```
SELECT Patient.id
      ,User.familyName
FROM Patient 
    INNER JOIN User ON Patient.userId = User.id 
WHERE User.familyName LIKE '%doe%';
```

But again, I haven't found a solution to joins either using jugglingdb.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use the include functionality as long as the relationship exists. For example:

```
Patient.belongsTo(User, { as: 'user', foreignKey: 'userId' });

// Empty callback for async getter.
var c = function () { };

Patient.all({ 
    where: { blah: blash }, 
    include: [ 'user' ] 
}, function (err, patients) {
        var user = patients[0].user(c);
    }
);
```

You can even include relationships to the relationship. For example:

```
Role.belongsTo(User, { as: 'role', foreignKey: 'roleId' });

Patient.all({ 
    where: { blah: blash }, 
    include: [ { user: 'role' } ]
}, function (err, patients) {
        var user     = patients[0].user(c);
        var userRole = user.role(c);
    }
);
```

It is important to note that sometimes the returned relational object(for example the "role" object) may be read-only. I have not dug too deeply into the reasoning behind this, so I cant give you a confident answer as to the why, how, or where this occurs, but I believe it may be within JugglingDB itself.

Comment: I must also mention this only works with a many to one relationship and not many to many. There is however, a [fork](https://github.com/iwtsolutions) that supports includes on a many to many relationship

Comment: If I run the first example, it will do `SELECT * FROM Patient`, followed by `SELECT * FROM User WHERE id in ...`. If the Patient table has thousands or millions of results, this would not be ideal.